# Creating a binary Tree from a text file written in pre-order

Tags: java, tree

I have a series of Tree Nodes stored in a text file in pre-order. To create the tree I have a TreeNode class that contains the nodes payload and a TreeNode for left and right if it isn't a leaf.

```java
class TreeNode{
    private String payload;
    private TreeNode left;
    private TreeNode right;

    public TreeNode(String payload){
        this.payload = payload;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }

    public TreeNode(String payload, TreeNode left, TreeNode right){
        this.payload = payload;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public void setLeft(TreeNode left){
        this.left = left;
    }

    public void setRight(TreeNode right){
        this.right = right;
    }
}
```

I need to be able to take the lines from the text file (which are the "payload" for each node) and re-create the tree from them. I believe the best way to do it is via a recursive function like one used to traverse a created tree in pre-order however I cannot wrap my head around how to do it.
The code I have for getting the lines from the text file stores them in a variable once I've read each line. I did this because I believed it would make it easier to work with the data as I am not very familiar with reading text files in java.

```java
public TreeNode loadTree(){

    File file = new File("suggestions.txt");

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        int len = 0;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            len++;
        }
        int pos = 0;
        String[] lines = new String[len];
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            lines[pos] = lines;
            pos++;
        }

    } catch (IOException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am relatively new to Java so I apologise for any stupid code.

Comment: Just having nodes in pre-order does not allow you to rebuild the original tree.

Comment: How do you expect to be able to read past the end of the file?